# Refactoring websocket code that uses global variables into events / async programming

Tags: javascript, websocket, global-variables, refactoring

There's a bit of someone else's code I am trying to add functionality to. It's using websockets to communicate with a server which I will most likely not be able to change (the server runs on a 3$ micro-controller...)

The pattern used, for instance when uploading data to the server, consists in using global variables, then sending a series of messages on the socket, as well as having an 'onmessage' which will handle the response. This seems clumsy, given that it assumes that there is only ever one socket call made at a time (I think the server guarantees that in fact). The messages sent by the server can be multiple, and even figuring out when the messages are finished is fiddly.

I am thinking of making things so that I have a better handle on things, mostly w.r.t. being able to know when the response has arrived (and finished), going to patterns like

```
function save_file(name, data, callback) {

}
```

And perhaps at some point I can even turn them into async functions.

So couple of ideas:
 - is there some kind of identifier that I could find in the websocket object that might allow me to better string together request and response?
 - short of that, what is the right pattern? I started using custom events, that allows me to much better tie the whole process, where I can supply a callback by attaching it to the event, but even doing removeEventListener is tricky because I need to keep reference to every single listener to make sure I can remove them later.

Any advice anyone?

Comment: If there is only one call at a time (a request message and a response message), keeping track to string them together should be trivial?

Comment: Global variables have nothing to do with this directly, assuming there is only a singleton socket instance it's not a problem that they are global instead of being e.g. instance properties. You can (and probably should) do that refactoring separately from changing the event processing pattern.

Comment: Well, it's more complicated than that, the protocol, say, for uploading data is: - client sends message to specify the request (using some complicated binary packing), then set the mode to 'started', then wait for a response. After this response, send the data in packets of 1024Kb, sequentially. Then wait for a final response code. In that case, yes, it is not too hard to keep track of where we stand, but so my question is also: what is the right pattern to turn all this spaghetti code into something with more cohesion.

Comment: For those who are curious, here's the code (after some of my changes) - check
line #267 ws.onmessage - 
https://github.com/joelhoro/webrepl/blob/master/webrepl.html

Comment: Bergi - yes, about the fact they're global, I guess I should stick them on a singleton, which would have the benefit of giving them some kind of namespace instead of just hanging about in the global scope.

Comment: I see, thanks. Given that you don't have long sequences of commands, I don't think async/await will be of much help here. Your application is far too interactive for that. The custom events seem like a good idea, I haven't checked yet where you are handling them. What's the use case for adding and removing listeners there?

Comment: Regarding the protocol, it's simple enough that you should go for a state machine. Have a state variable on your singleton and receive events from both the websocket responses and the ui

Comment: Well, the reason I am attaching events is a workaround to having a single global variable that holds a callback (that would get triggered at the spot where currently I am sending the signal). But with hindsight, I think it's not a great idea. Events are probably great when several places in the code would trigger them, and the event handler is somewhat permanent. But in my case, I set the callback, then wait for the signal to arrive, and as soon as it's there I delete the handler. That's actually kind of dumb... will scrap that

Comment: Ok, for that case a promise will be better suited, resolved by protocol state machine